# Windows 10 IE11 Compatibility Mode

Tags: windows-7, internet-explorer, compatibility, microsoft-edge

I have been using Windows 8.1 Pro for awhile and i can access this webpage by adding it into compatibility view in IE.

Then I decided to upgrade to Windows 10 via the preloaded options given.

I tried to open the webpage again as it is part of my company's site. Even using "Open in IE" option from Microsoft Edge and adding the website to the compatibility mode , does not allow me to see the webpage.

Is there anything i can do?

Comment: Can you share the URL to the website? If the site renders in IE11 on Windows 8.1, it should also work in IE11 on Windows 10 since they are largely unchanged but we'd need to reproduce the problem first.

Comment: @CharlesMorris-MSFT - Hi Charles , sorry for the late reply..

Unfortunately its an intranet-based and also was not developed by our company.

And no , the site does not render in IE11 on W8.1 , we had to use Compatibility Mode for that.

I found a way to open the site now , but i have to open dev menu (F12) and set the compatibility to IE9 while not closing the dev menu.

I am wondering if there's a way i can set the default compatibility mode to IE9.

Comment: if you have access to the source of the app, you can add an `x-ua-compatible` header to [the main page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj676915(v=vs.85).aspx).  Alternatively, the administrator of the server may be able to [configure the server](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj676913(v=vs.85).aspx)  to include the header.  If neither approach is available, you_may_ be able to [control default rendering](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj676914(v=vs.85).aspx)  with your copy of IE, but that can be, er, fritzy in practice.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your internal site requires IE9 document mode which is still supported in IE11 on Windows 10.

Two options to set the default compat mode for that site to IE9:

1. If you can update the site code, you can add the following meta tag to all of the site pages to make it request IE9 mode.

   <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=9">
2. If your intranet has managed PCs, you can use the [Enterprise Mode Site List feature](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt270205.aspx) to add specific sites on your intranet to load in specific document modes in IE.

Comment: Hi Charles,

i've read about x-ua and also edge's compatibility tag needed to be added to the site, but that is beyond my capability. Though i can forward this to my IT HQ.

Anyway , is there a way to set the compatibility mode default as IE9?
For my current method , i had to use Dev Mode (F12) and set it to IE9 manually.

Comment: No, you can't set the default mode as IE9 AFAIK.